# Fundamental group of $S^{1}$ unioned with its two diameters

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Is my solution correct?

Call $X$ the riflescope space (I made this name up). I let $p$ be the point of intersection of the two diameters, and $q$ be the right point of intersection of the horizontal diameter with the circle. I let $A=X-{p}$ and $B=X-q$. Then $A \cap B = X-p-q$. $A$ and $B$ are open path connected with $X = A \cup B$. Furthermore $A \cap B$ is simply connected since it deformation retracts to a point. $A$ deformation retracts onto $S^{1}$ so has fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}$ and $B$ deformation retracts onto a space homotopy equivalent to the theta space which I know has fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$. I conclude by van Kampen that $\pi_{1}(X) \simeq \mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$.

> Okay so my original solution isn't correct. I have a feeling that it's the product of 4 copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ but I'm not sure how to decompose $X$ yet.

Comment: If I understand which points you are calling $p$ and $q$, then $A\cap B$ is not path-connected. Note, you need $A\cap B$ to be path-connected in order to use the Seifert-van Kampen Theorem.

Comment: You can contract one diameter, giving you the wedge of two spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your space looks like $\bigoplus$ then it is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of *four* circles (collapse the diameters to a point) so Van Kampen gives its fundamental group is the free group on four generators (not three).

Comment: Why can we collapse the diameters to a point? Is this using the homotopy equivalence criterion: If $(X,A)$ is a CW pair consisting of a CW complex $X$ and a contractible subcomplex $A$, then the quotient map $X \rightarrow X/A$ is a homotopy equivalence?

We never covered this in class but that seems useful.

Comment: @Andrew For example, yes. The cross formed by the lines is a contractible subcomplex.